Add plot.ly to shopify blog
I created an interactive plot with plot.ly and want to integrate it into a shopify blog article.
What I would do:

save the code into an .js in assets

window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};                                    
if (document.getElementById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")) {                    
  Plotly.newPlot(                        
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",                        
    [{"hovertemplate":".......................................................


link it in the blog html or in a liquid with

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ 'myplot.js' | asset_url }}"></script>

The Plot is not visible... What am I missing?
Shopify asset

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The approach you're taking to integrate a Plotly chart into a Shopify blog article is mostly correct. Here are a few things to check that might help get the plot to display properly:
Make sure the Plotly library is added before your script docs :
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.35.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Ensure the ID in your JavaScript matches the HTML element

In your JavaScript: Plotly.newPlot("plot-container", data, layout);
In your HTML: <div id="plot-container"></div>

Wrap your Plotly code to run after the page is fully loaded:
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // your code goes here
    });
</script>

Finally, check for console errors that might help identify the issue.

Thank you very much!!! It should work this way. I think there is still something with my plotly code in shopify, although it works on it's own...
